# Locus of global sections with positive dimensional zero locus is Zariski closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an $n$ dimensional smooth projective variety and $\mathcal{F}$ a globally generated rank $n$ locally free sheaf on $X$.

> Question: Is the locus of sections $s\in H^0(\mathcal{F})$ having a positive dimensional zero locus Zariski closed?

My idea: denote by $s_1,\dots,s_{m}$, $m=h^0(\mathcal{F})$, a basis for $H^0(\mathcal{F})$. Then we get a map
$$G:X\to Gr(m-n,m),$$
where $Gr(m-n,m)$ denotes the Grassmannian of $m-n$ planes in $\mathbb{C}^m$. This map sends a point $x\in X$ to subspaces formed by those $\underline{\lambda}=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m)\in\mathbb{C}^n$ for which $s_{\underline{\lambda}}(x):=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i s_i(x)=0$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is globally generated this is indeed an $m-n$ plane. Then we have the following
$$X\stackrel{G}{\to} Gr(m-n,m)\stackrel{\pi_2}{\leftarrow} \mathcal{U}\stackrel{\pi_1}{\to} \mathbb{C}^m$$
where $\mathcal{U}$ is the universal subspace bundle. Then the zero locus of $s_{\underline{\lambda}}$ is
$$G^{-1}\pi_2\pi_1^{-1}(\underline{\lambda}).$$
Now I would want to use some sort of upper semicontinuity result to conclude, but I cannot quite figure out how.

An idea for how to finish the above argument, or an alternative argument, or a counterexample to the statement, would all be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Here is a standard argument: in $\mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathcal{F}))\times X$, consider the subvariety $Z$ of pairs $([s],x)$ such that $s(x)=0$. This is clearly closed, hence projective, and you are looking at the sublocus of  $\mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathcal{F}))$
 where the fibers of the projection $Z\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathcal{F}))$ have positive dimension. This is closed by semi-continuity of the dimension of the fibers (e.g. EGA IV 13.1.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put my comment as an answer. Yes, the result is true. Here is a standard argument: in $\mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathcal{F}))\times X$, consider the subvariety $Z$
 of pairs $([s],x)$ such that $s(x)=0$.
This is clearly closed, hence projective, and you are looking at the sublocus of $\mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathcal{F}))$ where the fibers of the projection $Z\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathcal{F}))$
 have positive dimension. This is closed by semi-continuity of the dimension of the fibers (Chevalley's theorem, see e.g. EGA IV 13.1.5).

Comment: Do we not need the projection $Z\to \mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathcal{F}))$ to be surjective for this argument?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The locus where the fibers have positive dimension is closed in the image, which is itself closed.

Comment: Basic question, but why is the image closed?

Comment: Any morphism of projective varieties is proper; in particular, its image is closed.